# C++ 20 experimental std Modules not accessible with latest MSVC experimental tools enabled

Tags: c++, visual-c++, module, c++-experimental

The following doesn't compile with what is latest and greatest from Microsoft MSVC.  Advertised last year as able to run the following:

Project Settings Changed:

```
/EHsc                 (required: C++ exceptions)
/MD                   (required: Multi-threaded DLL)
/experimental:module  (required: enable C++ 20 standard [experimental] modules)
/std:c++latest        (required: enable latest draft)
```

app.cpp:

```
import std.core;

int main(int argc, const char* argv) {
    std::cout << "test\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I got interested from reading this post:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170

I simply cannot get it running.  My version is Visual Studio 2022 17.1.4, the latest version.  I have all build tool versions installed that are available for selection. I started with the latest, and that gave me this error so I added more, and that did nothing. Everything C++ and SDK-related are installed.

```
fatal error C1011: Cannot locate standard module interface. Did you install the library part of the C++ modules feature in VS setup?
```

And that's not actually a 'package' you can select from in the installer.  I do have all the build tools for all C++ versions.  I suppose it didn't install it but I have no idea what else I can install here.  I have absolutely everything selected.  I think this feature was simply broken for this release but I cannot downgrade to an older version as used in the tutorial.

Comment: You need to have "C++ Modules for v143 build tools (x64/x86 - experimental)" checked under individual components in the installer.

Comment: You are my hero.  I missed it.  I will make sure it works and post an answer, or you may.